# Rust associated type bounds on supertrait from subtrait

Tags: rust

I am trying to write code that deals with transition systems. Right now, I am using a `TransitionSystem` trait, which has (amongst others) associated types `EdgeColor` and `StateColor`, giving the type of color used on edges and the type of color used on states, respectively. To be as general as possible, the implementation allows using a special `Void` type in either position (i.e. on edges or on states) to indicate the absence of a real color.

Now I am trying to add subtraits to `TransitionSystem`, which are essentially just marker traits indicating that on a certain position (either states or transitions), a type is used which has certain desirable properties (in my code that means it implements the `Color` trait).

Is there a good way of expressing this through the subtrait itself? I have already found a way of expressing that the supertrait necessarily needs to use an associated type which implements `Color`, but the resulting code is quite verbose. I have cooked up a small example to illustrate what my issue is, what workarounds I've tried and what I am actually after:

Imagine a trait such as

```
trait Super {
    type Out;
}
```

Now all implementors of `Super` have an associated type `Out`, but some `Super`s are unlike others and the associated type satisfies some additional bounds, which we would like to capture in a subtrait of `Super`. We can currently do it as so:

```
trait SubWithBound: Super
where
    Self::Out: Eq,
{
}
```

But now, whenever we want to accept a `Super` where the associated type `Out` implements `Eq`, we have to be quite verbose about it. The following code does not work

```
fn sub_with_bound<X: SubWithBound>(x: X, y: X) {
    if x.eq(&y) {
        panic!("Equal")
    }
}
```

And to make it work, we additionally have to specify `where X::Out: Eq` in the signature of `sub_with_bound`.

A workaround that I am currently experimenting with is to say that we have an additional associated type on the subtrait, put the trait bounds on that and then force equality of the associated type of the super and subtrait. Something similar to the following:

```
trait SubCheat: Super<Out = Self::OutBound> {
    type OutBound: Eq;
}
```

Now while that does seem to work, the type system can no longer figure out the appropriate types, when I have a method that accepts two different implementors of `SubCheat` where the associated type is equal. So the following code

```
fn sub_cheat<X: SubCheat, Y: SubCheat<Out = X::Out>>(x: X, y: Y) {
    if x.eq(&y) {
        panic!("Works")
    }
}
```

does not work and instead of specifying equality of the `Out` associated type, I have to resort to the `OutBound` associated type.

Is there any way of expressing what I want to achieve in a more concise and less confusing way? Essentially, I would like the following:

- have a (super)trait `Super` with an associated type `Out`
- have one or multiple subtraits `Sub1,Sub2,...` of `Super`, which restrict the associated type `Out` of the supertrait `Super` to implement `Bound`
- whenever I now use a trait bound `X: Sub1`, it should automatically be enforced that `X::Out: Bound` without me having to specify that in every place.

Sorry for the lengthy and convoluted explanation. If something is still unclear, I am happy to clarify it further. I am thankful for any input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not seem to be possible until [RFC 2089: Extended implied bounds](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2089-implied-bounds.md) is implemented.

For discussion on your exact problem, see [this thread](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/52662#issuecomment-473678551).